# Internet Access unavailable in browsers and mail. But Youtube and Google Play worrk fine

Tags: browser, bugs

[EDIT] after further diagnosis I observed that I am unable to access my router via its (local)ip address in chrome but I am able to access my router via edge browser.

Chrome in my android device is unable to access any website(can't open this page error) but at the same time, it works in the Microsoft Edge app. The chrome gives some suggestion link but when I click on the suggestion link a screen overlay comes up Similar to the image below, but the overlay quickly vanishes(I suspect whatever process was called, it crashes).

I observed similar behavior in my Gmail app, when I load an click on an email it tries to open it and quickly crashes(after showing loading similar to the image below). Although I am still able to open attachments in Gmail app.

Almost all other apps like youtube, google play are working nicely.

I am using an Android device with Android Pie(9). 
This problem happened Suddenly whilst the phone was idle.

I have tried disabling these apps, clearing storage, starting in safe mode.

Chrome error:

[image: Chrome error]

Loading screen after which crashes take place look something like this:

[image: Loading type screen after which crashes take place]

Comment: Please show us the error messages you get in the web browser(s).

Comment: @Robert I updated the question, when I click on learn more. An loading overlay occurs and the overlay crashes and I am back to this "can't open this page screen".

Answer (score 0):

I have now disabled my chrome browser and which has allowed me to use Gmail and other apps that were crashing.
There is some problem with Google Chrome App, which leads to other apps crashing(maybe they use chrome[or its API] as a default backend).